# VB.NET getting error: Class 'Application' must implement 'Sub InitializeComponent()'

Tags: vb.net, entry-point

I'm doing a VB.NET WPF application using VS2013, and I am just trying to find and use the right entry point.

I have read tons of answers on this, one saying something and the other saying the opposite. Mainly they say: the entry point of your project is the autogenerated main() you can find in your Application.g.vb. Yes, ok, very nice but...it is a generated file, not a good idea to modify it. So I searched the net on how to implement my own main() method, and the common answer I've found is:

- Select Application.xaml and change its build action to "Page"
- Create your own main method in Application.xaml.vb with this signature:

  _
  Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim app As Application = New Application()
      app.InitializeComponent()
      app.Run()
  End Sub
- Go to your project properties, untick "Enable applpication framework" and select Sub Main as startup for your application.

And so I have done but I continuously get this error:
**Error 3   Class 'Application' must implement 'Sub InitializeComponent()' for interface 'System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector'.**

this is the Application.g.i.vb file it generates:

```
    #ExternalChecksum("..\..\Application.xaml","{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}","DB788882721B2B27C90579D5FE2A0418")
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Automation
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.Windows.Data
Imports System.Windows.Documents
Imports System.Windows.Ink
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Windows.Markup
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows.Media.Effects
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging
Imports System.Windows.Media.Media3D
Imports System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting
Imports System.Windows.Navigation
Imports System.Windows.Shapes
Imports System.Windows.Shell


'''<summary>
'''Application
'''</summary>
<Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Public Class Application
    Inherits System.Windows.Application
    Implements System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector

    Private _contentLoaded As Boolean

    '''<summary>
    '''InitializeComponent
    '''</summary>
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")> _
    Public Sub InitializeComponent()

        #ExternalSource("..\..\Application.xaml",4)
        Me.StartupUri = New System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)

        #End ExternalSource
        If _contentLoaded Then
            Return
        End If
        _contentLoaded = True
        Dim resourceLocater As System.Uri = New System.Uri("/FatLink;component/application.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)

        #ExternalSource("..\..\Application.xaml",1)
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Me, resourceLocater)

        #End ExternalSource
    End Sub

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0"), _
     System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never), _
     System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes"), _
     System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity"), _
     System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")> _
    Sub System_Windows_Markup_IComponentConnector_Connect(ByVal connectionId As Integer, ByVal target As Object) Implements System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect
        Me._contentLoaded = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

so...as Sub InitializeComponent() is there, why the hell do I keep getting this error?

**EDIT:**My Application.xaml.vb is just that:

```
Partial Public Class Application
    <System.STAThreadAttribute(), _
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")> _
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim app As Application = New Application()
        app.InitializeComponent()
        app.Run()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: And your _whole_ code that contains the Main function is?

Comment: I have just added the Sub Main to Class Application, still not doing anything else in that file. I have edited the post to add the while file, by the way.

Comment: _Partial Public Class Application_

Comment: unfortunately I have already tried it and it does not work. Editing my post to add "Partial Public" as it makes sense, by the way.

Comment: Did you remove the StartupUri entry in the Application.xaml?

Comment: If you want to whine, complain, and rant, write a blog post on your own site. Here is not the appropriate place.

Comment: Sorry Ken, it was just an outburst I was about to remove by myself.

Comment: @Steve: i didn't. Tried now, it compiles and the error disappear but the mainwindow is not shown anymore (as in the initializeComponent now the uri point to application.xaml). Is that correct? how can I run mainWindow then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce you problem:

1. Create a new WPF VB.NET application
2. Create the custom `Main` in the `Application.xaml.vb` file as from your post
3. In the project properties uncheck the `Enable Application Framework` (automatically the startup object becomes our Main sub)
4. Set for the Application.xaml file the `Build Action` property to `Page`

At this point, the line that call `app.InitializeComponent()` is underlined with a red squiggle to signify that the project cannot find the InitializeComponent method. If you try to compile at this point you get the mentioned error.

Final step:

In Application.xaml file remove the

```
  StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
```

Now the squiggle disappears and the compilation ends correctly.

If you want to start you own main window you could change the Run line with

```
 app.Run(New MainWindow())
```

Comment: Thank you again Steve. You are right, this way the error disappear but the MainWindow is not started so the application just starts, but nothing appear. Should I run somehow manually the main xaml?

Comment: app,Run(new MainWindow())

Answer (score 0):

If you get that error, you probably haven't stated that your app is to start with your Main() method. So:

"Go to your project settings and untick the Enable application framework checkbox (if it's ticked) and select Sub Main as the Startup object , then add your main-method to Application.xaml.vb (plus the logger and other stuff)."

When you have done that, VS won't create "its own" Main-method and will rather call the one you defined in Application.xaml.

Taken from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7ef493f-27be-4f32-8ff4-a014078f572c/custom-systemwindowsapplication-in-vb-net?forum=wpf

Check also this: http://ugts.azurewebsites.net/data/UGTS/document/2/3/32.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer Romias, but I have read that post on msdn social and I did what suggested there (check on my post, I mention it)

Comment: About your EDIT: already read that link too, and it is the reason I wrote "someone saying something someone saying the opposite". At the end of the page you posted, it states: "..point to the Startup Object to 'Sub Main' and 'Enable application framework'. That means "Tick" the checkbox MSDN says to "UNtick".

Comment: Ok, if your read and applyed both approaches and doesn't work... don't know what could it be.

Comment: thank you anyway for your help...I'll keep trying of course, I'll post the solution when I'll find it.